# ANTLR - accessing token values in c/c++

Tags: c++, antlr, token

I am trying to parse integers and to access their value in antlr 3.2.

I already found out how to do this in Java:

```
//token definition

INT :  '0'..'9'+;

//rule to access token value:

start : val=INT           {Integer x = Integer.valueOf( $val.text ).intValue(); }

;
```

... but I couldn't find a solution for this in C/C++. Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but in that code, you're parsing a string into an `Integer`, converting it to an `int`, then auto-boxing it back into an `Integer`.  You could skip the `intValue` step, or change `x` to be an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

According to `examples-v3/C/C.g` from http://www.antlr.org/download/examples-v3.tar.gz, `$INT.text->chars` should work for C but I didn't test it.

If you traverse an AST from outside of the parser in a C program and you have a node named "node" of type `ANTLR3_BASE_TREE` you can access it with `node->getText(node)->chars` (tested since I use this myself).

Remember that the C and the C++ target are two completely different things. I only use the C target so I can't say much about the one for C++.

Nevertheless the examples are a great resource to learn about such details that unfortunately aren't documented very well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply $INT.text->chars returns a char pointer and solves the problem.